# Need help testing a method in java

Tags: java, netbeans, junit, junit4

I have the following code:

```
for (empCount =0 ; empCount < NUMBEROFEMPLOYEES; empCount = empCount + 1)   
{
    System.out.println("Ref NO: " + spRefNo[empCount] + "  \tSalespersons Name:  " + 
    spName[empCount]);
    System.out.println("..............................................."); 
    System.out.println("Type in the salespersons monthly sales");
    System.out.println("...............................................");
    spMonthlySales[empCount]=InOut.readDouble();


    //If to calculate sales persons monthly sales over 10000 pounds
    if (spMonthlySales[empCount]>=10000)
    { 
        spCommission [empCount] = (spMonthlySales [empCount] * (HIGHCOMRATE/100));
        spGrossPay [empCount] = STAFFBASIC + spCommission [empCount];
        spDeductions [empCount] = (spGrossPay [empCount] * (DEDUCTIONSPERCENTAGE/100));
        spNettPay [empCount] = (spGrossPay [empCount] - spDeductions [empCount]);
    }
}
```

I'm looking help writing a test for this code in JUnit - I know how to test the values that are calculated, but I don't know how to simulate the user input that the method asks for.  The code is mostly irrelevant, I'm not worried yet about how to test it, it's just the user input I need to simulate in the test, I think.  Anybody able to help me with this, or point me in the right direction to find an answer?

Comment: Split your code in two method. One to take the input and the other only for processing purpose. Hence you test the processing method.

Comment: This seems like the best thing to do, but it's for an assignment, and I'm not sure if I can rewrite the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest rewriting the function to take something like a `Scanner` object ([javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)). You can have a `Scanner` on `System.in` in your production code, and have a `Scanner` on a `String` object (e.g. `Scanner sc = new Scanner("This is a test string")`) in your tests.

Comment: It's for an assignment, and I don't think I can rewrite the code.  Is there any way to do it as it is?

Comment: StackOverflow is giving `InOut` syntax highlighting, but what actually is it?

Comment: It just reads user input from the keyboard, it seems like the readDouble() will validate or try to parse the input as a double, if I type a letter, it returns to the start of the for loop with the output error of "Error: Not a Real Number".  Actually seems quite handy, it seems to negate the need to write any sort of validation loop, it just does it itself.  There's a separate class called InOut that seems to handle keyboard input, that uses java.io, and System.in.read() to read the input.

Comment: Actually, disregard my last comment, it just accepts keyboard input, and checks to see if it's a double, if it isn't then it just returns 0.0, and continues through the loop, it doesn't ask for input again.

Answer (score 0):

You could provide input and test output with the [System Rules](http://stefanbirkner.github.io/system-rules/) library.

```
public class YourTest {
  @Rule
  public SystemOutRule log = new SystemOutRule().enableLog();
  @Rule
  public TextFromStandardInputStream systemInMock = emptyStandardInputStream();

  @Test
  public void test() {
    systemInMock.provideLines("first", "second");
    ... //execute your code
    assertEquals("First!\nSecond!\n", log.getLogWithNormalizedLineSeparator());
  }
}
```

Full disclosure: I'm the author of System Rules.

Comment: Thanks very much, I'll give this a try, see how it goes.